# Creating a user-input filters on csv file that contains large data

Tags: python, csv, coding-style

I have a program that open and read a file in csv format that contains large data such as:

```
State      Crime type Occurrences Year 

CALIFORNIA ROBBERY    12          1999
CALIFORNIA ASSAULT    45          2003
NEW YORK   ARSON      9           1999
CALIFORNIA ARSON      21          2000
TEXAS      THEFT      30          2000
OREGON     ASSAULT    10          2001
```

I need to create 3 filters by user input. For example:

```
Enter State:
Enter Crime Type:
Enter Year:
```

If I enter:

```
Enter State: CALIFORNIA
Enter Crime: ASSAULT
Enter Year:  2003

Crime Report
State      Crime type Occurrences Year
CALIFORNIA ASSAULT    45          2003
```

This needs to happen.

I have no clue on how to tackle this problem.. I was only able to open and read the data file in csv format into a table in Python that will just print out every line. However, I need to incorporate search filter to narrow the result such as shown above. Anyone familiar with this? Thank you all for your help.

Comment: A couple of clues: 1. Get user input. 2. Open the CSV file and read it row-by-row and check if the contents of each one match the value(s) the user specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pandas library in Python allows you to view and manipulate csv data. The following solution imports the pandas library, reads the csv using the `read_csv()` function and loads it into a dataframe, then ask for input values, keeping in mind that State and Crime should be string values and cast as `str` and Year should be integer and cast as `int`, then applies a simple query to filter the results you need from the dataframe. We build this query keeping in mind that all three conditions should be met and that the input strings can be lowercase too.

```
In [125]: import pandas as pd
In [126]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

In [127]: df
Out[127]:
        State Crime type  Occurrences  Year
0  CALIFORNIA    ROBBERY           12  1999
1  CALIFORNIA    ASSAULT           45  2003
2    NEW YORK      ARSON            9  1999

In [128]: state = str(input("Enter State: "))
Enter State: California

In [129]: crime_type = str(input("Enter Crime Type: "))
Enter Crime Type: robbery

In [130]: year = int(input("Enter Year: "))
Enter Year: 1999

In [131]: df.loc[lambda x:(x['State'].str.lower().str.contains(state.lower()))
     ...: & (x['Crime type'].str.lower().str.contains(crime_type.lower())) & (x
     ...: ['Year'] == year)]
Out[131]:
        State Crime type  Occurrences  Year
0  CALIFORNIA    ROBBERY           12  1999
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your help.
Is there a way to do this without using pandas module? I'm a newbie at writing Python and I would like to figure this out without using modules.

Comment: You are welcome! If this has answered the question, consider upvoting/accepting as answer.

Comment: I just did! I'm testing out the code now but I would like to know if there is a way of using user-input filters to narrow search result from a csv file

Comment: Python's standard library has the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)  module that can help you work with csv's. With Pandas, you get the advantage of viewing your data. If you are working with large data, pandas is recommended over the csv module.